# Line and distance to lattice points?

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices, diophantine-approximation

Consider the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^{n}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a line (not necessarily through the origin).

What conditions can be placed on the slope of the line that is necessary and sufficient so that the Euclidean distance from lattice points to the line are arbitrarily close to $0$?

Note that the lines does not necessarily pass through the origin, otherwise Minkowski's theorem would have solved it.

Thank you.

Comment: A necessary condition coming from [Kronecker's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem) is that the components of the direction of the line are linearly dependent over $\Bbb{Z}$. Undoubtedly you knew about this. Sufficiency? Would it be enough that (in addition to that) the line won't pass through a lattice point? Looks like a compactness argument might then be enough. I don't have the time to think this through now.